# How to disable wp resizing nav bar into an icon

Tags: wordpress

I currently have a site http://rinique.com/, When the browser is resized to around mobile phone resolution, the nav bar automatically convert into a orange drop down list.

Is there anyway to disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Read about [css media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and some advise/idea about your site:

You have a `css` file [here](http://rinique.com/wp-content/themes/mystile/css/layout.css?ver=3.5.1) (layout.css) and this is responsible (also could be `js` file too) for showing things differently on different devices. Notice, `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}`, in this block you'll find `ul.nav`, `ul.nav li` and suchlike things, these are actually a different style rules for handheld devices like, `tablet`, `smart phones` etc. So, if you want change the responsiveness of your site, you may alter these rules and check what happends after you've made a change.

Also, in your `general.js` file [here](http://rinique.com/wp-content/themes/mystile/includes/js/general.js?ver=3.5.1), you have

```
// Responsive Navigation (switch top drop down for select)
jQuery('ul#top-nav').mobileMenu({
    switchWidth: 767,                   //width (in px to switch at)
    topOptionText: 'Select a page',     //first option text
    indentString: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'  //string for indenting nested items
});
```

I think this code is also doing something for the `nav` to be response according to device/screen size. So, that's it, change and see, just play with these codes and see what you get but make sure to `backup` these before you make changes to these files and I personally like and would like to give you an advise that, your site is better with support for responsiveness and you should keep it as it is. So, think again before you revoke the feature (responsiveness) from your site.